# Display option data with php and hide the similiar

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using php to select data from my database. I'm displaying it in a HTML select option tag. I have 100+ options and I want to hide which is the same as my selected data. For example:

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" required>
    <option selected value='<?php echo $type; ?>'><?php echo $type; ?></option> // for example $type == "c"
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

For example the $type variable is "c". So it displays the option "c" twice. How can I easily hide always the one that I need if I have 100+ option values?

Comment: Need to see the structure of the array you use for generating the options. If you have the options hard-coded, you will need javascript. If not, simply unset the array member matching the selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Manually remove all duplicate option tags with JavaScript and jQuery

```js
let values = []
$("option").each((index, item) => {
  let { value } = item //item.value is the value of our current option in the loop
  
  // check if value is already in values array
  if(values.includes(value)) {
    // delete duplicate from the DOM
    item.remove()
  } else {
    // push value to values array so that duplicates can be detected later on
    values.push(value)
  }
})

console.log(values)
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" required>
    <option selected value="c">c</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Alternative solution

If your given options a, b, c, d are always the same you could setup a „blacklist“ in your PHP code and only echo out the html option element if it‘s not in this blacklist. Is this a possible solution for you?

Comment: Sadly no. I have several select tags, each has 100+ option values.

Comment: Just to be sure I got it right: Every select tag of your options are provided by PHP? So the static options a, b, c, d in your code example above were just an example output of your PHP script?

Comment: No, those are static options. Only the first one is dynamic, but I must display the element from the database, so I can't make a "blacklist". And I have several select tags, so I'm looking for something that easier than making 1000+ lines of code because of the amount of my options data.

Comment: If you can‘t make a blacklist that contains all the static options you provided, you could use JavaScript on the client-side to remove all the duplicated options.

Comment: Could you show me an example how to do this with js?